# Spring data solr HttpSolrClient does not use core annotation from entity

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

With a configuration as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages={"com.foo"}, multicoreSupport=true)
public class SolrConfig {

    @Value("${solr.host}") String solrHost;

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient(solrHost);
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient());
    }
}
```

I have a simple entity:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core1")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
```

If using SolrTemplate to execute queries, it does not use the coreName annotation on the document:

```
Page results = solrTemplate.queryForPage(search, MyEntity.class);
```

I get exception:

```
org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.
[..]
Problem accessing /solr/select
[...]
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
```

Changing the SolrTemplate bean to:

```
@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
    return new SolrTemplate(solrClient(), "core1");
}
```

works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guys over at spring-data confirmed this is expected behaviour and the template won't read the core from the entity annotation.
So in a `multicoreSupport=true` environment, if you want to use both the repository and the template you'll have to create 2 beans:
For the repository the base template:

```
    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient());
    }
```

and for injecting you will have another one:

```
    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate customTemplate() {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient(), "core1");
    }
```

Obviously if you don't need `multicoreSupport=true` none is needed!